# Specify scroll owner for panel

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ScrollViewer` with layered content. E.g.:

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <Grid>
      <Child x:Name="Layer1" />
      <Child x:Name="Layer2" />
      <Child x:Name="Layer3" />
   </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The children need to be on top of each other and have the same size. Now, my `Child` class implements [IScrollInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Consider the grid above. I want to choose **one** child to be the owner of the `ScrollViewer`. Thus, "Layer1" would update the scrollbars and the other layers would just make sure that they have the same size as the scroll owner. Something like this would have been great:

```
<Grid ScrollViewer.ScrollOwner="Layer1">
```

Obviously, `Grid` is the wrong control to use here. Does WPF support something like the above out of the box? If not, what would be the best approach to accomplish this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing particularly elegant comes to mind. One (slightly tedious) option would be to subclass `Grid` to implement `IScrollInfo` and delegate all such functionality to the appropriate child, perhaps set via a property on the custom grid. i.e. along the lines of:

```
public IScrollInfo Scroller { get; set; }

bool IScrollInfo.CanHorizontallyScroll
{
    get { return Scroller.CanHorizontallyScroll; }
    set { Scroller.CanHorizontallyScroll = value; }
}
```

You'll need to watch that this redirection is arranged sufficiently early, before it is used by the `ScrollViewer`, which may be a pain.

Another option is to note that the `ScrollViewer` has a [`ScrollInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrollinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) protected property to point to the `IScrollInfo` child object. You could subclass `ScrollViewer` and set this, though this would seem a bit hacky - I just tried, and it's not clear when this would have to be set.

Lastly, you could consider that there is some design issue, that you have 3 siblings one of which is "more special" than the others - perhaps you really should have a custom panel containing these children which defines your `IScrollInfo` behaviour.

Note the term you use `ScrollOwner` is already a concept used in `IScrollInfo` to refer to the controlling scrollviewer.

Comment: This suffices as an answer as it sheds some light on `IScrollInfo`. Though, I ended up having *one* child of my `ScrollViewer` with the other children outside - binding to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the first child.